# Recent activities log

Tags: logging, recents-screen

Is there an easy way to view a list of recent activities? The one I'm looking for doesn't seem to be showing up in the main recent apps view, and `adb logcat` is so noisy I'm having a hard time finding anything.

Comment: What kind of recent activities are you looking for?

Comment: Really just any activity that is appearing on screen.

Answer (score 2):

For Lollipop do `adb shell dumpsys activity recents`. For some earlier Android version, run `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`.

Alternatively, you may run `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -i run` as noted by loeschg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387875/view-activity-stack-in-android#comment18798819_4387944).

You would get a list of recent apps' package name, component (activity) name, flags among other things.

In Lollipop, if you've root access, you can browse to `/data/system/recent_tasks/`. You'll find some XML files with numeral names, such as `317.xml`. Each of them consists of the same aforesaid details, but each XML file is created for an individual app.

You can also get some info from `adb shell dumpsys usagestats`.